# WCFService's DBContext to MVC App?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have created a 'WCFService' application under 'WCFSolution' solution and generated the DBContext using Entity Framework from a Database 'DemoDB' in 'WCFService' application. and also created some CRUD methods in WCFService (Which is working great).

[image]

Then I created an empty 'WCFMVCApp' MVC application under the same solution ('WCFSolution') and also added the service reference to this app. Now i needed to create a controller ('HomeController') with the DBContext that is generated in that WCFService, so that i can generate the views based on the WCF models while creating the controller.

I could create a new EF in WCFMVCApp but it would defeat the purpose of WCF. Any way to do this. or is it possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think a better design would be to move all EF models and DTOs to a third assembly and reference it in both. Adding a WCF project as a reference to a Web Application project is bad practice in my book.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EladLachmi, Could you please point me out to some tutorials based on that concept. I'm a total newbie.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff628208  - Here is a video tutorial. You need to create a new `Class Library` project type and move all the EF, model object to it. Once this is done, you need to update all the references in both of your existing projects to reference this new assembly. Since this is effectively only a namespace change, all existing code should continue to run after you update the namespace for the data objects and context.

Comment: I tried that tutorial and it works well but 
it works like this http://i59.tinypic.com/mhtzbs.png
1. WCF refers EF
2. EF access DB in WCF
3. MVC refers EF
4. EF access DB in WCF

There is no purpose in using WCF right. What i want is, 1. MVC refers EF
2. MVC calls WCF
3. WCF refers EF
4. EF access DB in WCF
and MVC must not have direct access to DB in wcf using EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a WCF Service, in your MVCProject you don't have a DbContext to deal with and you should not add a reference to your WCF Service. You have some options.

Solution 1: Use a client

In your MVC Project create a data service client. Your service should be running and you need the data service tools installed. Then you can add a service reference and some proxy classes are generated for you.

[WCF Data Services 5.6.0 RTM Tools Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39373)

Solution 2: Add a DbContext dll

You can have your DbContext living in a seperate class library that you reference in your service and your MVC project.

In both cases you are using DataServiceContext to perform CRUD operations. For the second one you may have to add an an implementation for `ResolveType`. To get an idea how to do this, this is how the automatic generated DataServiceContext would resolve types:

[ODataSamples](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/blob/master/Scenarios/CustomFormat/ODataSamples.CustomFormatServiceDemo/CustomFormatServiceProxy.cs)

```
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.OData.Client.Design.T4", "2.1.0")]
    public Container(global::System.Uri serviceRoot) : 
            base(serviceRoot, global::Microsoft.OData.Client.ODataProtocolVersion.V4)
    {
        ....
        this.ResolveType = new global::System.Func<string, global::System.Type>(this.ResolveTypeFromName);
        ....
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Since the namespace configured for this service reference
    /// in Visual Studio is different from the one indicated in the
    /// server schema, use type-mappers to map between the two.
    /// </summary>      
    protected string ResolveNameFromType(global::System.Type clientType)
    {
        global::Microsoft.OData.Client.OriginalNameAttribute originalNameAttribute = (global::Microsoft.OData.Client.OriginalNameAttribute)global::System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(global::Microsoft.OData.Client.Utility.GetCustomAttributes(clientType, typeof(global::Microsoft.OData.Client.OriginalNameAttribute), true));
        if (clientType.Namespace.Equals("ODataSamples.CustomFormatService", global::System.StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            if (originalNameAttribute != null)
            {
                return string.Concat("ODataSamples.CustomFormatService.", originalNameAttribute.OriginalName);
            }
            return string.Concat("ODataSamples.CustomFormatService.", clientType.Name);
        }
        return null;
    }
```